# Characters javascript

Tags: javascript, php, special-characters

I have this

```
<?php
    echo "<script> $('#new-agency').click(function(){
         $('#AgencyTable').append('<tr id=/'3/'><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><input type=/'button/' class=/'updagetAgency/' value=/'Update/'/></td><td><input class=/'addAgency/' type=/'button/' value=/'Add/'/></td></tr>'); 
       });</script>";
?>
```

I am having problem with it, because of the mixing of ' and " in the same string,

I tried using '/' to escape but it doesn't seem to work,
what can I do?

Comment: Just will leave it there `\\`

Comment: use back slash (\\) instead of (/)

Comment: You should only escape the character that the string is encapsulated in. In this case the `"`. escaping the `'` is useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason here to use PHP! You needn't have an `echo` call at all.

```
<script>
    $('#new-agency').click(function(){
         $('#AgencyTable').append("<tr id='3'><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><input type='button' class='updagetAgency' value='Update'/></td><td><input class='addAgency' type='button' value='Add'/></td></tr>"); 
    });
</script>
```

The other aspects of this problem:

- inside a string delimited by `"`, there is no need to escape `'` characters, and vice versa so we use `"` to delimit the string and `'` for the quotes inside it
- the escaping character is actually the backslash `\`, not the forward slash `/`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape it with \ (Back slash)

Comment: it works, I was in a hurry I wrote a slash instead :)
but I thought what @lonesomeday said is true, here I don't need php and echo,